# How to generate a random number that does not repeat

Tags: java

I'm writing a MasterMind program in Java. My intention was to generate a 4 digit number, but all digits need to be different. How would you do that using `Math.random()`? Or is there a better way?

example:

```
4321 (allowed)
4341 (not allowed)
```

Comment: What did you do so far? You could just repeat using `math.random()` until there's no duplicate digits in your result.

Comment: It is customary when asking a question to show us what you've tried so far.  The solution to this problem is a simple exercise in algorithm formulation.  You would benefit more if you tried to come up with an approach yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Collections to determine that you already have this digit:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyRandom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getRandom(4));
        System.out.println(getRandom(4));
        System.out.println(getRandom(10));
    }

    public static String getRandom(int length){
        if (length>10) return "Hexadecimal?";
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (length>0){
            int digit=(int)(Math.random()*10);
            if (numbers.contains(digit)) continue;
            numbers.add(digit);
            length--;
        }
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        for (Integer integer : numbers) {
            sb.append(integer);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Maps gives you cleaner code and better complexity

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> fourUniqueRandonNumbers = new HashSet<Integer>() ;
    int maxItems = 4;
    StringBuilder flatValueToRetun = new StringBuilder();
    while (fourUniqueRandonNumbers.size()<maxItems){            
        int randomNumber = (int )(Math.random() * 9 + 1);           
        if(!fourUniqueRandonNumbers.contains(randomNumber)){
            fourUniqueRandonNumbers.add(randomNumber);
            flatValueToRetun.append(randomNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this using `Collections.shuffle` method.

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
Collections.shuffle(l);
Integer result = 1000*l.get(0) + 100*l.get(1) + 10*l.get(2) + l.get(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really optimized here, but :

the simple/brutal way would be to generate digit by digit, and as you store them, as long as you get a digit you already have, you'll generate a new random digit.

A better solution would be to initially store the possible digits (let's say in a list), and for each digit you would get a random number up to the size of the list (minus 1 as list starts at 0), get the element at this position, and remove the element from the list.

Example :

```
Possible digits : 123456789
picks a random element, let's say "3"
Possible digits : 12456789
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to solve this problem, I have provided two below.

**First one:**

Using a random generator, add random digits from 1-9 to a set.
Set prevents duplicates, so continue generating until the set size is 4.

**Second one:**

Add the digits 1-9 to an ArrayList, use Collections.shuffle to shuffle the numbers.
Take the first 4 numbers.

**Note:** Not using the digit 0, to prevent 0123 from becoming 123.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            setRandom();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            shuffleRandom();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Use a random generator, generate digits from 1-9,
     * add them to the set (prevents duplicates) until set size is 4
     */
    public static void setRandom() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

        while(set.size() < 4) {
            set.add(rand.nextInt(9)+1);
        }

        String numStr = "";
        for(Integer n : set) {
            numStr += n;
        }
        int num = Integer.parseInt(numStr);
        System.out.println(num);
    }

    /**
     * Add digits 1-9 to an ArrayList, shuffle it using Collections.shuffle
     * Take the first 4 digits
     */
    public static void shuffleRandom() {
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            intList.add(i);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(intList);

        String numStr = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            numStr += intList.get(i);
        }
        int num = Integer.parseInt(numStr);
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3459
1359
2589
3456
2198
2153
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to choose between 4 things, then the 3 remaining, then the 2 remaining, now take the last . How about:

```
n1 = generator.nextInt(4)+1;

n2 = generator.nextInt(3)+1; 
if (!n2<n1) {n2 += 1;}//avoid the hole 

n3 = generator.nextInt(2)+1; 
if (!n3<n1) {n3 += 1;}//avoid the holes 
if (!n3<n2) {n2 += 1;}
```